# Command line option to uncheck Azure Extension during SQL Server 2022 setup

Tags: sql-server, azure

When installing SQL Server 2022 (16.x), is there a command line argument or configuration file option that can skip the Azure Extension for SQL Server step, or at least leave the **Azure Extension for SQL Server** checkbox unchecked?

[image]

I thought `/FEATURES=SQLEngine` (since the extension is installed by `/FEATURES=AZUREEXTENSION`) would do the trick, but Azure Extension is still enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

from cmd according to the documentation it should be **/FEATURES=SQL**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver16

When I created via Wizard configuration file(2022 creates Settings.xml), so there is:

```
<Setting Id="FEATURES" Value="SQLENGINE" Source="UI" IsApplicable="true" IsChangeableByUser="true"/>
```